# why is this regular expression is not working so well

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, str-replace

I try to make a function that returns true if a string follows a certain pattern

here is the PHP code

```
<?php


function patternn($p) 
{
  $p="%".$p."%";
  return $p;
}

function like_match($pattern, $subject)
{
    $pattern = str_replace('%', '.*', preg_quote($pattern, '/'));
    $result=preg_match("/^{$pattern}$/i", $subject);  
    return $result;
}



$name="144";
$keywordd="14";

$pa=patternn($name);

$ch=like_match($pa,$keywordd);

echo $ch;
?>
```

when $name=144 and $keywordd is 144 or anything before 144 and after it returns true
but the thing I want the function to returns true when $keywordd is 14 or 44

Comment: Your pattern is `^.*144.*$` which will not match 14 or 44. You want to match 2 digits, where the pattern accepts at least 3 digits..

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: If you want to match 14, 44 or 144 try `^(?:1?44|14)$`

Answer (score 1):

Why arent you using `strpos` for your simple matching?

```
<?php

function like_match($haystack, $needle){
    return (strpos($needle, $haystack) !== false);
}

$name="144";
$keywordd="14";

$ch=like_match($keywordd,$name);

var_dump($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your RegExp pattern is okay. Just some logical problem.

```
<?php
function patternn($p) 
{
  $p="%".$p."%";
  return $p;
}

function like_match($pattern, $subject)
{
    $pattern = str_replace('%', '.*', preg_quote($pattern, '/'));
    $result=preg_match("/^{$pattern}$/i", $subject);  
    return $result;
}



$name="144";
$keywordd="14";

// Corrected
$pa=patternn($keywordd);

// Corrected
$ch=like_match($pa,$name);

echo $ch;
?>
```